# Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress

I get this error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in [wordpress dir]/wp-content/themes/[my-theme]/functions.php on line 14"

And line 14 is just a simple `use` command...

Line 13-15:

```
add_action('headway_setup_child_theme', array('HeadwaySchematic', 'init'), 1);
use mfbcaptheme\mobilebrowsertheme;
require_once 'mobilebrowsertheme.php';
```

This is on a client's site and it works just fine on my test site....Not sure what would cause this error.

Comment: Please reopen this question. The answer to this question - upgrade PHP 5.2 to 5.3 was relevant to a lot of people in 2013 and is still relevant today. So it is likely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 42):

Make sure they are running PHP 5.3 or later. If they are running an earlier version they won't have support for namespaces.

Comment: So you don't see any syntax errors? than it must be php version

Comment: This is one of those answers that has me going 'ahhhhhh' in a sudden moment of realisation.