# Phpmailer not working on webserver

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to get phpmailer to work on a web server. It does work with no problem on my xampp server but as soon as I put it on the web server it cant find these and it gives me the error. I also tried putting it on another web server and that doesn't work. I also copied the files from my xampp server to the web server and it still doesn't work.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; (line 3)
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception; (line 4)


Error: parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '('email.php on line 3
```

the code that the error points to is

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
function sendemail(){



require '../mail/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../mail/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    include "removed(was database)";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $Uemail = $_POST['email'];
    $select = $_POST['select'];
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];
    $resolution = $_POST['resolution'];
    $datesubmited = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  //1-4                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'removed';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'removed';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'removed';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = removed;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $email = 'removed'; //put in default email that corresponds with the username / passwoard.
    $mail->setFrom( $email, 'removed');
    $mail->addAddress($Uemail, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('removed', 'removed');
    $mail->addAddress('removed', 'removed');     // Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('', $name);


    //Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Request from ' . $name;
    $mail->Body    = 'Details ' . "<br>" .
    "Date: " . $datesubmited . "<br>" .
    "Name: " . $name . "<br>" .
    "Email Address: " . $email . "<br>" .
    "Area of Concern: " . $select . "<br>" . 
    "Issue: " . $issue . "<br>" .
    "Suggested Resolution: " . $resolution . "<br>"; 




    $mail->AltBody = 'Hello '. $name . ' your request has been sumbited!'.'</b>';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
);
    $mail->send();
    echo "Thank you " . $name . " for your submission." . "<br>" . "Someone will repsond to you shortly.";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Go back home " . "removed" ;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
} 




?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance I would say that the `use` function seems to call the problem. Could you try adding these lines before your first `use` call and check the result:

```php
$funcDefinition = new ReflectionFunction('use');
print $funcDefinition->getFileName() . ', ' .
  $funcDefinition->getStartLine();
```

Check the results of the call on your local and your remote systems and compare the outcome. I don't think that you are deploying on Pre-PHP-5.3 systems where the `use` command was not available but please also add some information regarding the different PHP versions used locally and remote.

**In fact it seems** that you get your error message in case you are deploying on PHP 5.2 systems as this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960277/error-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-t-constant-encap) mentions. So first check has to be the PHP version (i.e. by adding a `phpinfo();` before your first `use` call).

**Conclusion:** question author received the error due to deploying on a PHP 5.2 system without `use` support.

Comment: the php version is  Version 5.2.3 on the web server and on the xampp server is PHP Version 5.6.33.  Is the older php the reason it is not working?

Comment: Yes, that will be the reason it's not working - PHP 5.2 lacks support for namespaces and imports. You should absolutely not be using PHP 5.2; it's been out of support for years and you're also running a very old and vulnerable version of it. If it's what came on your server, get a new server.

Comment: @JangoFrost as mentioned by Synchro and in the linked SO thread, PHP 5.2 does not support namespaces, support was introduced in [PHP 5.3 as can be seen in the release notes](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php). Please upgrade to the most recent version as all your public applications running on PHP 5.2 may contain critical security gaps.